# To print nth fibonnaci number without recursion

Tags: fibonacci

I am solving a problem to print nth Fibonacci term without using recursion on an online judge.
It says to print the output modulo 1000000007.

```
#include <stdio.h>
long long int fib(int q)
{
 if(q==1||q==2)return 1;
 else{
  long long int x=1,y=1,z;
  register int i;
  for(i=0;i<q-2;i++){
    z=x+y;
    y=x;
    x=z;
  }
  return z%1000000007;}
}
int main(void) {
 int t,i;
 scanf("%d",&t);
 for(i=0;i<t;i++)
 {
    int q;
    scanf("%d",&q);
    printf("%lld\n",fib(q));
 }
 return 0;
}
```

The code is working fine in code blocks but it is showing wrong answer(also it does not show output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing:

- Please indent your code to be as much readable because then it helps use provide you better answers and people easily understands the code

And the bug is with modulo.
You are required to provide answer modulo *1000000007*.
And the fibonnaci sequence grows really fast.

Then what might happen is the long long type overflow.

You must calculate modulo on each step of algorithm.

Lets see the following example:

- x and y are very large but still fit into long long type
- the x+y does not fit into long long
- then x+y is some negative value because (overflow happended)
- we calulate fibonnaci sequence with negative numbers!

With modulating when summing we always get

- x+y % 1000000007
- That is always less than 1000000007 so the sum always fits into long long
- So we have no overflows!

The final code with that change looks like this:

```
long long int fib(int q) {
  if(q==1||q==2) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    long long int x=1,y=1,z;
    register int i;
    for(i=0;i<q-2;i++){
        z=(x+y) % 1000000007;
        y=x;
        x=z;
    }
    return z % 1000000007;
  }
}
```